# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' within virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a python project that i setup using a virtualenv (pipenv). i use `pipenv shell` to create the virtual environment and from within their im able to run my script using `python main.py`

**main.py**

```
import tkinter
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Im trying to display a plot but i get the following error:

> File
> "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/**init**.py",
> line 36, in 
> import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

I have tried doing `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` and recreating the virtual env but this it did work.

1. Is there another way i can display a plot without tkinter? `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`
2. Can i install tkinter from within the virtualenv?
3. Can the virtualenv access the machines version of tkinter (python3-tk)

**Python 3.8.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you can use a different [matplotlib backend](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) that will work within a virtual environment because we can install it via pip.

**install**

```
pip install Qt5Agg
```

or

```
pipenv install Qt5Agg
```

**usage**

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the use of `tkinter` in `matplotlib` using the following declaration

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

'`agg`' activates a backend different from `tkinter`

Comment: This does NOT work. UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()